# How do I query the filenames in an Oracle logical directory created using CREATE DIRECTORY?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do I query using SQL or PLSQL so that I can get the filenames in an Oracle logical directory created using CREATE DIRECTORY?

Suppose the following script is executed to create the directory:

```
create or replace directory my_directory as '/var/tmp/mydirectory';
```

Using SQL or PLSQL, how do I get the filenames of the files in directory `my_directory`? If the directory contains the files `my_file_1.txt` and `my_file_2.txt`, I should get 2 rows.

I don't need the files' content but just the filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a really easy PL/SQL API for this.  Some day, this will be in the `utl_file` package.

One option is to write a small Java stored procedure that populates a temporary table.  Here is an [AskTom example of a Java stored procedure that lists the files in a directory](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).

There is also a trick using the `dbms_backup_restore` package but that requires you to query an `x$` table which is technically undocumented.  Here is an example of [using `dbms_backup_restore` to list files in a directory](http://www.morganslibrary.org/hci/hci002.html).

Personally, the Java stored procedure strikes me as easier to read, easier to secure, and more likely to work consistently moving forward.  But if you want a pure PL/SQL solution, you can look at `dbms_backup_restore`.

Comment: `ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission (java.io.FilePermission /var/tmp read) has not been granted to USER1. The PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission( 'USER1', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/var/tmp', 'read' )
ORA-06512: at "USER1.GET_DIR_LIST", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.`

Comment: That's what I get following the Java approach.

Comment: So I tried this one
`exec dbms_java.grant_permission( 'USER1', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/var/tmp', 'read' );`

Comment: and got `Error starting at line : 57 in command -
exec dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SAGEDBO', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/var/tmp', 'read' )
Error report -
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.SecurityException: policy table update SYS:java.io.FilePermission, /var/tmp
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JAVA", line 793 ORA-06512: at line 1
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be 
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not int`

Comment: @supertonsky - What user are you running the `grant_permission` as?  What user owns the Java stored procedure?  If the user that you are running `grant_permission` as does not have the `java_admin` role, you may need to grant the user `grant_policy_permission`.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chten.htm#BABBGAEC  Or you could have your DBA run the grant (that seems more sensible-- you're not generally in a position where you can or should be granting privileges to yourself...